# Horizontal space before TikZ picture

Tags: tikz-pgf, line-breaking, margins

The horizontal bar from the following MWE does not start at the left edge of the paper as expected, but rather a bit more to the right. The line is 17cm long and the page width is also 17cm, which results in the warning

> Overfull \hbox (1.59978pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 9--10

I tried adding '%' signs at the end of all the lines without any effect. What am I missing please?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, showframe, margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[ultra thick] (0,0) -- (17,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are not missing anything; apparently TikZ adds some padding equal to the line width (you can see this by using different values for `line width` in your `\draw`). You can prevent the undesired space using the `overlay` option (either globally for the whole `tikzpicture`, or locally for just the `\draw`):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, showframe, margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[overlay,ultra thick] (0,0) -- (17cm,0);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

Comment: @cfr I believe this is only because of your [node referencing `current bounding box`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/701518/why-do-lines-drawn-in-tikz-add-space-equal-to-their-width-into-the-picture-and-h#comment1744420_701518). This answer still produces the same output. However, the TikZ picture reports a box of zero size back to TeX. (It basically `\smash`es and `\rlap` the diagram.) Try `Foo\tikz[overlay]\draw[ultra thick] (0,0) -- (17cm,0);Bar` to see that more clearly. For a simple horizontal line on its own paragraph, this is okay.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel I didn't realise Ti*k*Z had such a crazy bb to begin with. Thanks.